# Why doesn't Vieta's formula work for $x^{3}-2x^{2}+ 2x - 1= \frac{15}{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I thought that Vieta's formula worked for all equations, until I encountered this exercise:

> What is the sum of all the real solutions $x$ of the equation $x^{3}-2x^{2}+ 2x - 1= \frac{15}{x}$?

After simplifying the equation, I figured that the answer is $2,$ by Vieta's formula. However, by factoring, we find that the sum of the real roots is actually $1.$ Why doesn't Vieta's formula work here to find the sum of roots? In what situations can I use it?

Comment: Is it because there are some non-real solutions?

Comment: Yes, but does vietas not work when there exists imaginary solutions? If so, how can I tell when I can/can't use the formula without having to always factor the equation first?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "vietas"?

Comment: https://oeis.org/wiki/Quartic_formula#Vieta.27s_formulas_for_the_quartic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using Vieta’s theorem, the equation $$x^3-2x^2+2x-1=\frac{15}{x}$$
must first be rewritten as a polynomial:
$$\implies x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x-15=0$$
(notice that $x\neq 0$). The **sum of its roots** is indeed $-\frac{b}{a}=-\frac{-2}{1}=2$.

Even so, the question asked for **the sum of its real roots**, whereas
Vieta’s formulae give the sum of its complex (including real) roots. That is, the above “sum of its roots” might have contained something like $1+i$ and $1-i,$ and two other roots that cancel each other.

Thus, instead of Vieta's theorem, this exercise requires another technique, such as factoring, as you said, or by using the rational roots theorem.